# I want to clear specific row values in a database, using this for loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to clear specific row values back to null, I have a prototype for loop that I would like to use. However I am afraid that it will delete everything in the table. The database has columns: user, password, correct, wrong, and game1, game2, game3.....game16. I want to clear the columns that start with game, but nothing else. It seems simple to do, however I cannot seem to make it work. Can someone help me understand?

```
$vals=array();
$sql="DELETE "; 
for ($i=1; $i<=16; ++$i) {
  if (isset(game$i)) { continue; }
  if ($i != 1) {
   $sql .= ",";
  }
  $sql .= "game$i=:game$i";
  $vals[":game$i"]="game$i";
  "game$i FROM user WHERE user = * ";
}

$statement=$db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($vals);
```

Comment: are you missing something near: `"game$i....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a value to `NULL` is an `UPDATE`, and different than removing the record from the database (`DELETE`)

To prevent having to dynamically create you SQL Statement, it looks like you can (and probably should) just write out the whole SQL Script.

```
UPDATE u
SET u.game1 = NULL
   , u.game2 = NULL
   , u.game3 = NULL
   , u.game4 = NULL
   , u.game5 = NULL
   , u.game6 = NULL
   , u.game7 = NULL
   , u.game8 = NULL
   , u.game9 = NULL
   , u.game10 = NULL
   , u.game11 = NULL
   , u.game12 = NULL
   , u.game13 = NULL
   , u.game14 = NULL
   , u.game15 = NULL
   , u.game16 = NULL
FROM user AS u
```

`FROM user AS u` makes an alias for user, so I can reference the table with the single character `u`.  You see this happen when I specify the UPDATE u (using the alias). [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) probably does a better job explaning SQL Aliases than I will.

You do not need (and should not have) a `WHERE` clause if you want the `UPDATE` to affect all the users, this is implied by not having a `WHERE`

Comment: @CraigSmith I didn't see the homework tag until just now...  Is the loop a requirement?

Comment: No it isn't a requirement, just thought it would work, however I am totally open to other ways of doing it.

Comment: I didn't clarify in the question, I would like to do this for every user in the table. Would it work if I just used your code, and did
    "FROM user = *"

Comment: @CraigSmith since it isn't a requirement, I would recommend you not use the loop, and instead explicitly write the `UPDATE`. It is slightly longer than what you currently have, but I would argue it's much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Easier to read is definitely a plus. I am not interested in performance, I just need it to work.

Comment: @CraigSmith This statement, without a `WHERE`, should give you what you want then.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, delete = dropping the record

If you looking to set the column value to NULL, you can do this :-

```
 UPDATE {$table}
 SET game{$i} = NULL, ...; // you don't even need a user = *
```

Comment: That makes sense, would that work for every user in the table? Because that is what I would like to do.

Comment: Yes, spent some time reading mysql document on the update syntax will do good for you